# Set and get session variable on callback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session, devexpress

I am using Devexpress controls in asp.net c#.
I have a GridView with a **CustomButtonColumn**. When I click on that button it performs a callback and gets the row key. There I set a **Session** variable with the row key.
On Page2 I want to use that Session to bind a parameter in a XtraReport.

```
[C#]
Page1

<script type="text/javascript">

        function OnClick(s, e) {         
            if (e.buttonID == "SF") {
                //Session["parameter_id"] = e.visibleIndex;
                //  gridAdmin.GetRowValues(gridAdmin.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'ID', OnGetRowValues);
                sf.PerformCallback(e.visibleIndex);

                window.location = "PrintView.aspx";
            }
        }   
    </script>

<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControl3" runat="server" CloseAction="CloseButton" ClientInstanceName="pcSF"
        AllowDragging="True" PopupAnimationType="None" Modal="True" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter"
        CssClass="panel1" Style="font-size: 20px" CloseOnEscape="true" HeaderText="SF">
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF8000" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <ContentCollection>
            <dx:PopupControlContentControl>
                <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="pnlSF" runat="server" BackColor="White" ClientInstanceName="sf" OnCallback="pnlSF_Callback" >
                    <PanelCollection>
                        <dx:PanelContent>

                        </dx:PanelContent>
                    </PanelCollection>
                </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
            </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
        </ContentCollection>
    </dx:ASPxPopupControl>

protected void pnlSF_Callback(object sender, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        Session["parameter_id"] = GridViewAdmin.GetRowValues(Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameter), "ID").ToString();
     //   Response.Redirect("PrintView.aspx");
    }

Page 2

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XtraReport1 repTest = new XtraReport1();

        repTest.RequestParameters = false;
        repTest.parameter1.Value = Session["parameter_id"];
        repTest.parameter1.Visible = false;
        repTest.CreateDocument();
        this.ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = repTest;
        this.ASPxDocumentViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```

**When I click on that custom button from gridview and loads page2 it appears this error.**
[image]

Why?

I saw that on debug when that error appears the callback is not done. It does not enter in **pnlSF_Callback()** function.

Comment: how you set validationKey  value

Comment: Do you refer to this ?                                                                `<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" /> </appSettings> `   or this `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`